# Scope not updated outside resource callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ngresource

I have a factory in AngularJS called WebService which returns a $resource object.

```
angular.module('cstarsServices')
.factory('WebService', function ($resource)
{
    return $resource("some_url_here/:op1/:op2/:op3/:op4",
            {op1: 'indexes'},
            {
                getIndexes: {
                    isArray: true,
                    method: 'GET'
                }

            }
        );
});
```

In one of my controllers, I call getIndexes:

```
WebService.getIndexes(function(data){

    // SearchIndex Table
    $scope.languages = [];
    var languages = [];
    var ajaxResponse = [];


    angular.forEach(data, function (item, i)
    {
        if (item.sourceTypes != null)
        {
            ajaxResponse.push({ selected: false, name: item.name, languages: item.sourceTypes[0] });
            languages[item.sourceTypes[0]] = item.sourceTypes[0];
        }
    });
    $scope.searchIndexes = ajaxResponse;


    for (var key in languages)
    {
        $scope.languages.push(languages[key]);
    }
    $scope.language = languages[0];
});
//This is undefined
alert($scope.searchIndexes);
```

However this doesn't seem to update the $scope correctly: for example the value of $scope.searchIndexes is defined and has the correct data *inside* of the function but is undefined *outside*. What's going on, and how can I get the $scope to update for the entire controller and not just inside the callback function? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WebService.getIndexes` function is making an asynchronous AJAX call.  The `alert()` command right below it is executed right after the `WebService.getIndexes` call is made, but before any data is actually returned from the back-end service.  Thus the `$scope` assignments you do within the AJAX call actually happens after the `alert()` command (or any other code in your controller that is not in a  function).

Try putting an `alert($scope.searchIndexes);` at the end of your AJAX call.  You'll notice that the output from this alert will actually appear *below* the output from your `alert()` outside of your AJAX call.

It's hard to recommend a work-around without seeing the rest of your controller.  But a general rule of thumb here would be to only reference `$scope.searchIndexes` within functions.  As long as those functions are then only called after the controller fully loads, you'll be able to reference `$scope.searchIndexes` without issue.